# Number of intersection of two closed curves on the Torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

[image]

Since the fundamental group of the Torus is $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$, any homotopy class of loop in the Torus can be represented as a $(p,q)-$curve (rational slope). Am I right?

On page 3 of [STEPHEN PATRIAS](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Patrias.pdf), he did not prove the above theorem. I checked the given reference and saw that the proof was left as an exercise. Any idea/hint on how to prove it?

Comment: Dear Jax, how about you post a question like this: let $(p,q)$, $(p', q')$ pairs of relatively prime integers. On the torus, consider the curves $C_{p,q}$, and $C_{p', q'}$. Show that they intersect in exactly $|p'q-pq'|$ points.  $C_{p,q}$ is the image of $[0,1]\ni t \mapsto (e^{i 2\pi p t}, e^{i 2 \pi q t})$.

Comment: I think what you said was the best reformulation of this question. Do you want me to edid my post or post a new one?

Comment: I think a new one would be better. You can give a link to this one too. I just think that I you will get more answers if it's not related to a specific article. They might  not necessarily look at it from a topology point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should say that the intersection number should be defined for homology classes. Now, $H_1(X) = \pi_1(X)^{\text{ab}}$, so no problems in this case.

Now, the intersection  pairing is a skew-symmetric bilinear map $H_1(X)\times H_1(X) \to \mathbb{Z}$. Now, $H_1(X)$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$ module with generators $e_1$, $e_2$. Therefore, we have
$$\langle p e_1 + q e_2, p'e_1 + q' e_2 \rangle = p q' - p' q \langle e_1, e_2\rangle = ( pq' - p' q)$$

Note that if $ pq' - p' q \ne 0$, all the intersections of the curves $p e_1 + q e_2$ and $p e_1 + q e_2$ have the same orientation. Therefore, the number of points of intersection of the curves is indeed $| pq' - p' q|$.

Comment: why is the intersection number defined only for homology classes?

Comment: @Jax: It is also defined for homotopy classes. But it passes down to the abelianization. So it's OK.  But you need to be able to deform loops without keeping a point fixed. Ultimately, you have it defined for homology classes, which is quite all right. Btw, it's more interesting for surfaces of higher genus. There, the intersection form has a nice basis $a_i$, $b_i$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Can you recommend me a textbook which I can use to well understand this concept, please?

Comment: @reuns: yes. We are calculating the number of common points. May assume that the slopes are not the same. Now, the important observation is that you can calculate this number as the absolute value of the intersection number of the two homology classes represented by these loops (reason is: each intersection point gives the same contribution ($+1$ or $-1$.). Now, for intersection pairing, we have some neat results (bilinearity, skew-symmetry ). So we are using some basic intersection theory. Of course if can be done purely combinatorialy, and one should try to write such a proof.

Comment: Yes I think I got it. At first we restrict only to closed-loops of the form $\lambda_i \to \lambda_j$ (straight line between two lattices points in $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$) but since we consider "signed" intersections, we can show the intersection number only depends on the homology class of the two closed-loops and extend the mapping to $H_1(X) \times H_1(X)$

Comment: @reuns: yes, and we do use bilinearity and skew-symmetry. I figure it's cheating in a way, but since it was a result in a topology paper, it was fairly obvious for the author. However, there should be a purely algebra-combinatorics proof.

Comment: @Jax: Czes Kosniowski course in topology comes to mind. Very down to earth. Best info/volume, and the info is easy to digest.

Comment: @reuns: yes, indeed. That is the idea, with the sign. You should see what happens on other surfaces of higher genus ( orientable) .....  Right now, I would like to see a proof without topology. All the intersections are rationals, so the reals might not even be mentioned.

Comment: And the same idea works in any orientable surface (we define the sign of the intersection as : when on (oriented) curve 1, does (oriented) curve 2 come from the left of the right). Did you mean $\langle e_i, e_i\rangle = 0$ so that $\langle e_i, e_j\rangle +\langle e_j, e_i\rangle = 0$ and $\langle p e_1 + q e_2, p'e_1 + q' e_2 \rangle = p q' \langle e_1, e_2\rangle+ q p' \langle e_2, e_1\rangle =  (pq' - q p')\langle e_1, e_2\rangle=pq' - p' q$

Comment: @reuns: yes, indeed. If we  started by just counting the number of points of intersection, it would not work so nice.  The signed intersections is the key.

Comment: @reuns: I think one important thing that topology give is that no matter how we deform our curves, the number of the intersection points will be at least |p'q - pq'|$.  This is indeed a topological result.